# How can I combine two sources of audio into one set of headphones?

Tags: microphone, mixer, headphones, hardware, interface

I am using my PreSonus AUDIOBOX 96 and Facetime in my computer to record a podcast. My current setup is: mic to AUDIOBOX and Soundflower to record audio from my computer. I don't have problems recording. But I would like to monitor both sources with one pair of headphones.

Currently I can only monitor one source at a time:

To monitor my mic I can use the headphone output in Audiobox but the computer outputs to built-in speakers which creates echo in my mic.

To monitor the computer output I plug my headphones to the computer headphone port.

So, my question is how can I hear both outputs in my headphones so I can hear the computer and my mic at the same time.

I red somewhere that a Mixer could hep but i'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a task I normally do using System tools, but I think you ought to be able to do it by creating a Multi-Output Device in Audio Midi Setup [Apps/Utilities].

Click the + button then check which devices you want to use as simultaneous outputs. Select the Multi as your output device in each desired App. If an app has no direct routing capability, set the Multi to be the default for sound output [Right click it, select. The speaker icon will move to it from wherever it currently shows.]

[image]

Comment: I tried that but I can only listen from Soundflower Input, not my mic. I can record both ouputs without problems though. For in I have an aggregate device with my mic and Soundflower. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Soundflower is meant to be the 'aggregator'. tbh, I haven't used it since it first started getting crashy, about Mavericks, so I'm not too sure any more. These days I use the far more reliable Loopback or Audio Hijack, both paid apps

Comment: I'm pretty sure multi-output is effectively a splitter, not a combiner. Send output to "multi-output device" and in this case, it will appear at the outputs of UX2 and 'built-in-output' with the UX2 being the master clock and the 'built-in-output' adapting it's stream to match.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you're probably right. I did say I haven't used this is a decade. Audio Hijack will definitely do this. Loopback is more expensive, but SoundSource might be able to do it, at a push.